# ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:

Tags: xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml using below code,

```
   if(f.exists())
            {
                doc = dBuilder.parse("/mySystem/Config/data/Settings/print-settings.xml");
            }
```

but I'm not sure why I'm getting below error while parsing the xml

```
More pseudo attributes are expected.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: 
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my xml encoding attribute was missing by adding same its get resolved

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?>
```